# Confusion about the output of this program

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am currently learning Data types revised chapter. In the below 
program, my o/p is 36 but compiler is showing the o/p 35.

```
main( )
{
char ch = 291 ;
printf ( "\n%d %c", ch, ch ) ;
}
```

Can anyone explain me why the o/p is coming 35? I am currently using GCC 32-bit compiler.

Comment: you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually making an overflow. A signed character can only go from values -128 to 127 (256 values = 2<sup>8</sup>) in 8-bit character systems (which are pretty much everywhere).
So we go with an actual character which value equals 291 % 256 = 35.

Don't forget that the first character is 0, not 1.

Here is actually how a char is represented with the [2's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
unsigned
0 ------- 127 128 ------- 255

signed
0 ------- 127 -128 ------- -1
```

So actually a `signed char c1 = -128` equals an `unsigned char c2 = 128`

But here this problem is just irrelevant. We're talking about modulo because only the last eight bits are taken into account (where would the other be stored when there are only eight bits available for it in the memory ?).

```
291 = % 1 0010 0011
```

(`%` means binary representation)

It keeps only the `% 0010 0011` which equals `35` and which will be considered exactly the same either you take it signed or not.

Comment: 0..255 — unless plain `char` is signed, when it usually goes from -128..+127.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer. But why you are taking the modulus here ? My understanding is that signed char has a range from -128 to 127. In the above code there is a overflow. So, for %c in the printf according to my understanding will give the following o/p 291-127=164,164-128=36. Therefore, it must give the o/p 36

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it, but since the modulo is under 127, `unsigned char` and `char` act the same.

Comment: No, you're getting the calculus wrong, it's actually simply 291 - 256 = 35, because your char is holding 8 bits

Answer (score 8):

Your system apparently has an 8-bit `char` type.  That means `291` is too big to fit - the compiler reduces it modulo 256 (2<sup>8</sup>) and you end up with 35.

In this case, [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) provides a great warning:

```
example.c:3:11: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value
      from 291 to 35 [-Wconstant-conversion]
char ch = 291 ;
     ~~   ^~~
```

You should probably avoid relying on this behaviour, since it may vary from implementation to implementation.  The C99 and C11 specs (Section 6.3.1.3) say about signed integer conversions:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Since you're using GCC, you might be interested to read this excerpt from [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> *The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 6.3.1.3)*.
>
> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2<sup>N</sup> to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

And there you have your full explanation of the reduction modulo 256.

Comment: My understanding is that signed char has a range from -128 to 127. In the above code there is a overflow. So, for %c in the printf according to my understanding will give the following o/p 291-127=164,164-128=36. Therefore, it must give the o/p 36.

Comment: But it clearly doesn't, as your example shows.  What does your compiler documentation say?  I don't understand why you're subtracting 127 and then 128.

Comment: But either if it's unsigned or signed it doesn't change anything. Take into account, that it is more like a range of 0 -> 128, -127 -> -1

Comment: I just went and looked up the docs for you - explanation added in my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Because a `char` can only contain 8 bits of information, and 291 require more than that to be stored. It will then discard the higher bits and keep only what fitted in the variable.

You can simulate that by both bitwise and module operation:

291 % 256 = 35

291 & 0xFF = 35

A 8-bit char can contain values of -128 to 127 or 0 to 255, depending if its signed or unsigned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why modulus here ? My understanding is that signed char has a range from -128 to 127. In the above code there is a overflow. So, for %c in the printf according to my understanding will give the following o/p 291-127=164,164-128=36. Therefore, it must give the o/p 36.

Comment: As I said its a simulation formula. The overflow happens in binary level, there is no arithmetic envolved.